# Lubuntu on Powerbook G4 not booting

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu, powerpc

Trying the alternate install CD for Lubuntu 12.10 for PowerPC on an old Powerbook G4. The install process seemed to go just fine, but trying to boot it up afterwards, I get this screen:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/24213190/error%20screen.jpg

At this point it's frozen, and about 10 minutes later it just powers down.

Side note: If this is significant, originally tried the standard Lubuntu install disc. The Lubuntu logo shows up but eventually freezes and shuts down before the option screen appears.

Comment: It looks to me like you have a failing hard disk. It may be worth scanning the drive for errors then posting any errors on your question.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Which diagnostic tool would you recommend in this case?

Comment: I'm afraid that I don't have a MAC, so I don't know what's available.

Comment: Just use the Disk Tool from the live disk.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a failed hdd.

Add "Linux snd-powermac.blacklist=yes" without quotes as an argument in yaboot and see if that solves it. Look at the following links for additional help.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCKnownIssues
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1066435